# Hive-Hbase integration - issues while inserting data

Tags: hive, hbase

I was able to successfully integrate Hive & Hbase for straight forward scenarios (No Partition & bucketing). I was able to insert data in both Hive & hbase for those simple scenarios.

I am having issues with Hive partitioned table stored in Hbase. I was able to execute "Create DDL" statement. When I try to perform Insert I get an error message saying "Must specify table name"

```
CREATE TABLE hivehbase_customer(id int,holdid int,fname string,lname string,address string,zipcode string) 
partitioned by (city string) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,personal_data:hold_id,personal_data:f_name,personal_data:l_name,personal_address:address,personal_address:zipcode") 
TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "hivehbase_custom", "hbase.mapred.output.outputtable" = "hivehbase_custom");

insert into table hivehbase_customer partition(city= 'tegacay') values (7394,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,29708);
```

Comment: How would HBase map your Hive partition since there's no such concept in HBase?

Comment: I agree with you. but, no where in the documentation it says "Does not support partitions". create DDL was successful. Also, insert fails with a weird error message. So, not sure whether it works or not.

Comment: Well since there is nothing in HBase that would implement some kind of partitionning this cannot work. Anyway be careful with HBase-Hive integration: this is mostly for development or testing purpose but I discourage using  that feature in production on big volumes.

Answer (score 0):

try following insert query

```
insert into table hivehbase_customer partition(city) values (7394,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,29708,'tegacay');
```

actually partitioned column needs to be specified as last column in insert query.